# How to use ternary operator using react with route?

Tags: reactjs

i want to use ternary operator with route using react.

what i am trying to do?
belwo are the conditions:

( condition1 or condition2 is true ) and user is in any url except "items/:itemId" display child1 component

(condition1 or condition2 is true ) and user is in only url "/items/:itemId" display child1 and another components

belwo is the snippet that displays Child1 component when route is anything and condition1 or condition2 is true

```
function Parent () {
    return (
        {(condition1 || condition2) &&
            <Child1/>
        )}
    );
}
```

i want to display child1 and another components when condition1 or condition2 is true and path is only "/items/:itemId"

**what i have tried?**

```
function Parent () {
    return (
        {(condition1 || condition2) &&
            <Child1 onHide={on_hide}/>
        )}
        <Route
            path="/items/:itemId"
            render={routeProps =>
                condition1 || condition2 ? (
                    <>
                        <Child1 {...routeProps} onHide={on_hide}/>
                        <Another />
                    </>
                ) : null
            }
        />

interface Props {
    onHide: any;
}

function child1 ({ onHide }: Props) {
    //somelogic
}
```

But this doesnt render anything at all. meaning not satisfying any of the conditions. could someone help me fix this? thanks.

Comment: Can you provide any details regarding your conditions?

Comment: Try your code with one of the condition as true

Comment: when i remove the Route thing from code it works...

Comment: @nir shabi: i have updated the conditions clearly

Comment: maybe that i am missing using routeprops in child1 component how should i pass routeprops to child1 component. update child1 component

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to render two components with react router like this. Instead create another component that has all your needed components inside.

For example (with es6):

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const renderComponent = () => {
    if (matchPath(props.location.pathname == '/items/:itemId') {
      return (
       <>
        <Child1 {...props.routeProps} onHide={props.on_hide}/>
        <Another />
       </>
      )
    } else {
      return <Child1 {...props.routeProps} onHide={props.on_hide}/>
    }
  }
  return renderComponent();
};

export default withRouter(Wrapper);
```

In your route component you can then do:

```
 {condition1 || condition2 ? (
   <Route
     path="/"
     render={(routeProps) => (
       <Wrapper {...routeProps} onHide={on_hide} />
     )}
   />
 ) : null}
```